# "unknown "mage_run_code" variable error" in NGINX on virtual machine

Tags: nginx, virtual-machine, virtualbox, magento2

I have reinstalled this virtual machine containing Magento multiple times and after about 10 minutes of use Nginx stops working and I start getting this error.

Comment: This question is unlikely to be sufficiently detailed to get a decent answer. Maybe you could look in your PHP logs?

Answer (score 0):

So my CTO figured out how to fix it immediately.  For anyone getting this error add this to your /etc/nginx/sites-available/{site} file.

```
map $request_uri $MAGE_RUN_CODE {
    default foo;
    ~^/bar bar;
    ~^/admin admin;
}
```